# face normals not displaying

Tags: normals

so I'm new enough to blender and I'm trying to teach myself a few things, I have flipped the normals on an object and I know I have to go into view port overlays to activate display normals but I am having trouble with getting the face displays to show. I've adjusted the size of the blue lines and I still cant get them to display. I feel like there's a setting or something that I'm missing any help would be appreciated.[image]
as you can see I have it activated and the slider is up full but the blue lines wont show on the selected object. and as a side note I have made a post about this a while ago but forgot my log in so I couldn't reply to the comments

Comment: Maybe your scene has a really unusual scale (far too big or far too small) ? As a workaround, you can tick "Face Orientation" (under Geometry). It will display faces Blue or Red based on their orientation, this may help you.

Comment: that actually helped a lot thankyou